# КОТОРЫЕ в начале предложения

Tags: грамматика, союзы, союзные-слова

Не раз замечал случаи, когда это слово занимает не привычное для союзного слова положение, а в самом начале фразы — с прописной. Ошибка ли это? Если нет, то почему так редки эти случаи?

> Но они не считают, что вероятный противник» на войну решится, чем
> оставляют себе простор для провокаций. Которые, разумеется, будут
> поданы как ответ на «агрессивные действия»... [Игорь Полежаев (2020)]
>
> Хочется в Грузию, к этим людям, которые так поют... Которые так поют — как нам нравится. [Евгений Гришковец. ОдноврЕмЕнно (2004)]
>
> Который является давним знакомым Александра Беспалова по совместной работе в мэрии Санкт-Петербурга. [И. Нагорных, И. Булавинов, А. Вешняков. Сверните поправки в трубочку // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2002]

Comment: Ну, [4600 вхождений в Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=capital+first&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2) — не так уж это и редко. Правда, там процентов 10 — вопросительные предложения. Не знаю, как их отфильтровать.

Comment: @grizzly: о, нашёл наконец, как вы сделали 'capital & first'! Сам раньше пытался такое в поиске задать (начало предложения) и ничего не получалось.

Comment: Действительно, диалогов много (Какие идолы? ― Которым ты поклоняешься), но к ним нет вопросов. И к тем, что с разговорным порядком (Которые кони овсяные, те и тижели не признают).

Comment: @grizzly [Отфильтровал](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=который&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=capital+first&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=-bques%2Clast&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2). Оказалось примерно 30%, а не 10.